# The set of all points of discontinuity of the function $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^{2n}(\pi x/2)$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, continuity

> Find the set of all points of discontinuity of the function
>   $$(\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}) : f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^{2n}\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$$

I stumbled across this problem while solving questions from the topic 'Continuity and Differentiability'.

I am not able to understand the general approach towards these type of problems where the discontinuous points of a limiting functions are asked. My attempt was to find out the limiting value and then analyze the result but that didn't get me anywhere. Any help towards solving these type of problems would be appreciated.

Comment: What you wrote is *a limit*. If it exists **finitely** that's a number, not a function (unless you meant a constant function, which I highly doubt), so what did you really mean? To ask what the discontinuity points are of the function $\;\left(\sin\frac{\pi x}2\right)^{2n}\;$ ? Is this a function both of $\;x\;$ and of a natural $\;n\;$ ? And if you meant this function, what does that limit mean then?

Comment: We have to find out the set of values values of 'x' where the function is discontinuous when 'n' approaches infinity.

Comment: I see, thanks.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your limit is $0$ whenever 
$$
\left |\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right|<1
$$
and $1$ if $\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)=\pm 1$.

So you have discontinuities whenever
$$
\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)=\pm 1
$$
well this occurs whenever 
$$
\frac{\pi x}{2}=\pi k
$$
for any integer $k$. Or when 
$$
x=2k
$$
an even integer. These are the points of discontinuity, since your function is 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x=2k,\;k\in \mathbb{Z}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Comment: 'k' should be an odd integer......Right?

Comment: $k$ is whatever integer you please. $\sin$ may output either $1$ or $-1$ and the limit will be the same since it is being squared