# The set of all points of discontinuity of the function $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2n}(x)?$

Tags: calculus

Could you please find the set of all points of discontinuity of the function  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2n}(x)?$

With the bests.

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579463/the-set-of-all-points-of-discontinuity-of-the-function-fx-lim-n-to-infty-s/2579480#2579480 for a nearly identical problem

Comment: I know this is nitpicking, but I must say I don't really understand why specifically for trigonometric functions we use the notation $f^k(x)$ to mean ${f(x)}^k$, when everywhere else we use it with da different meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, if $|\cos(x)| < 1$, this function tends to $0$. Otherwise, if $|\cos x|=1$, this functions tends to $1$. The discontinuities are therefore at every point where $|\cos x|=1$, and therefore the set of of points of the form $k \pi$ such that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

You can write $f(x)$ as
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1,\quad &x = k \pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
0,\quad \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$